# How do I resolve maui-check can not be found on mac m1?

Tags: .net-core, maui

I've been using redth's maui-check tool.  It works great on windows.  It runs fine on my intel mac.  On my m1 mac mini, it installs.  However, it does not run.  zsh reports that the command is not found.  I have installed the .net 6 core p4 build for arm macs.  I have also installed previous versions of .net core and mono. Any ideas on this?

Answer (score 2):

So, the summary of items that I had to install are:

- .NET Core 3.1 for Mac x64.  This resolves and issue about the version of maui-check assumes is on the system.
- .NET Core 6 for Mac x64.  This resolved a really weird startup error in maui-check.
- .NET Core 6 for Mac arm.  Duh.
- added my maui-check to the local path.

Once I did all of that, everything seems to be working now.  It is currently stumbling through a major set of updates.  I've found maui-check to run really well on my other systems.  I just need to run it multiple times because it sometimes misses things.  Great job Jon!

Answer (score 0):

Use Google which will lead you to this: https://github.com/Redth/dotnet-maui-check/issues/15